# How can I get player facing (like north, east, west or south)?

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am trying to get players facing, but my code doesn't work correctly.
I need this for my mod so I can boost with it.

I tried searching some methods which can return me facing but i didn't find any.

So I tried coding this :

```
String pdir = "";
Minecraft mc = Minecraft.getMinecraft();
float yaw = mc.player.getRotationYawHead();
if (yaw > 135 || yaw < -135) {
    pdir = "north";
} else if (yaw < -45) {
    pdir = "east";
} else if (yaw > 45) {
    pdir = "west";
} else if (-44 < yaw && yaw < 44){
    pdir = "south";
}
if (pdir.equalsIgnoreCase("north")) {
    mc.player.motionZ += (0 - Speed);
} else if (pdir.equalsIgnoreCase("east")) {
    mc.player.motionX += Speed;
} else if (pdir.equalsIgnoreCase("west")) {
    mc.player.motionX += (0 - Speed);
} else if (pdir.equalsIgnoreCase("south")) {
    mc.player.motionZ += Speed;
}
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work correctly". Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Answer (score 0):

By turning your direction into an Enum you can make your code cleaner and easier to manage:

```
public enum Facing {
   NORTH,
   EAST,
   SOUTH,
   WEST;

   public static Facing forDirection(float direction) {
      if(direction>=135 || direction<=-135) {
        return NORTH;
      }
      if(direction>=45) {
        return WEST;
      }
      if(direction<=-45) {
        return EAST;
      }
      return SOUTH;
   }
}

float yaw = mc.player.getRotationYawHead();
switch(Facing.forDirection(yaw)) {
  case NORTH:
    mc.player.motionZ -= Speed;
    break;

  case WEST:
    mc.player.motionX -= Speed;
    break;

  case SOUTH:
    mc.player.motionZ += Speed;
    break;

  case EAST:
    mc.player.motionX += Speed;
    break;
}
```